# API for Youtube Kids

Tags: search, video, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am trying to find Api for youtube kids, Youtube offers parameters like safe search but that will not return only results only for kids content. Is there any api available that will only return programs for Kids category.

Youtube-kids app only provides content that is child-friendly and curated for children. Is there any api that could help me get that results.

Some of the videos on Youtube Kids app is characterized under Film & Animation but it doesn't have any category specific to kids content

```
1 - Film & Animation 
2 - Autos & Vehicles
10 - Music
15 - Pets & Animals
17 - Sports
18 - Short Movies
19 - Travel & Events
20 - Gaming
21 - Videoblogging
22 - People & Blogs
23 - Comedy
24 - Entertainment
25 - News & Politics
26 - Howto & Style
27 - Education
28 - Science & Technology
29 - Nonprofits & Activism
30 - Movies
31 - Anime/Animation
32 - Action/Adventure
33 - Classics
34 - Comedy
35 - Documentary
36 - Drama
37 - Family
38 - Foreign
39 - Horror
40 - Sci-Fi/Fantasy
41 - Thriller
42 - Shorts
43 - Shows
44 - Trailers
```

What should be the approach to capture Kids only content via API ?

Comment: It's possible they **expect you to select your specifically required content** from given results. Consider creating a white-list of allowed channels, also maybe try checking the category/tags for each result then use `IF` statement to decide what to show in your interface from those search results.

Comment: But the question is how to identify kids only channels at first place. Then how do you set viewing category like this content is suitable for 2,4,8,12 years. We can scrap all data but making a Kids specific catalog is a challenge out of so much content available. The video category of kids content has "Film & Animation" mentioned but if i put this check it is also showing me other content that may not be suitable for a Kid.